# JSON Query execution Syntax error in DB2 LUW database

Tags: db2-luw

We have enabled the JSON support in our database (Db2 LUW- V11.5) and tried to run the query with JSON Function but ended up with the SQL error. Same query executed successfully in IBMi Database.

Is this related to the misconfiguration of JSON in the Db2 LUW system? Please advise on the below error.

This executed successfully:

```
SET TESTSCMA.JSON_VAR='[{"id":901,"name":"John"}]';
```

This failed:

```
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(TESTSCMA.JSON_VAR,'$' COLUMNS( NESTED '$[*]' COLUMNS("id"
 DECIMAL PATH '$.id',"name" VARGRAPHIC(20) PATH '$.name')));
```

> SQL Error [42601]: An unexpected token ")" was found following " )".
> Expected tokens may include: "<json_table_on_error_clause>"..
> SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.27.25

Comment: How did you enable JSON support? The new Db2 JSON functions don't need to be enabled. Is it this function you are trying to use? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070414.html?pos=2

Comment: JSON_TABLE function was not present in the installed Db2 database, so I have used the below steps to enable the JSON. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/t0061301.html

Comment: Yes, I'm using the JSON function from the shared link, but I'm accessing the data from Variable (SET TESTSCMA.JSON_VAR='[{"id":901,"name":"John"}]';)

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070414.html?pos=2

Comment: Please edit your question to show the text output of your query on IBMi for the given json fragment in the json_var variable.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 LUW has [two different types of JSON support](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/c0061252.html). The first is now called "[client access to JSON documents](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/c0061316.html)" and refers to some older BSON storage in Db2 with a MongoDB wire listener. It requires special enabling and installation.

The other, newer implementation is the one you want. It is [SQL access to JSON documents](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.json.doc/doc/c0070285.html) and built-in and requires Db2 11.1.4.4 and up. It includes the JSON functions based on the SQL standard, including the [JSON_TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070414.html?pos=2) you probably want to use. Note that it has a slightly different syntax than what you used in your statement. You are missing the `strict` keyword and some other grammar elements.

Comment: Meaning the error is related to the JSON support we are using. 
--- Im using statement of "client access" and the JSON Setup in DB database as "SQL access to JSON documents"

Comment: with SQL access, the JSON is stored as CLOB / BLOB. How do you store it? In your example above, you use a string.